# How to outsource with Github?

Tags: git, github, access-control

I am working with a company that wants to outsource the development of new features on one of our projects.  We have a github account and I am wondering how I can give the outsourcees restricted access to the project repo on that account.

Is there a way to limit commits and pushes on a repo to a specific branch with a specific set of credentials?

I've heard about forking but have never really used it.  Is that what I'm looking for?

**Update:**

It's funny looking back on this question now after three more years working in the industry.  I had a lot to learn.

Also, people are marking this post as off-topic, but I'm not sure that a more appropriate stack exchange site existed when I originally posted it.

Anyway, as people have pointed out, having the outsourcees fork the project would have been the correct way to handle this situation.  They would then have made pull requests which I could have reviewed and approved without giving them full access to our account.

Comment: It is nothing programming but management.  should be in other SO site, e.g.. programmers??

Comment: Gosh...after working in the industry for three more years and looking back on this question, it now seems very naive :).

Comment: @DennisCheung Honestly, I think when I asked this question the other stack network sites didn't exist :P.

Comment: @DavidSanders am facing a similar situation now - the guys you are outsourcing to - they would presumably have full access to your code base if you let them fork.....i want to restrict their ability to run off with all our code: do you know of a situation around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could fork the repository, grant access to that, and then keep pulling the changes into your main one - think of a fork as a private branch in this case.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction.  I think I'll have the outsourcers fork the project, and then I can easily manage integration of their changes by using the fork queue feature.  I don't think I need to give them full access to our main account this way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, forking does that for you. I think if you don't have experience working in a distributed environment, using your private Github repo, it would be wise to assess your team of developers (whom you're outsourcing the work to) for their expertise on usage of Github as a distributed/virtual team. Generally, if they are new to Github, it's really difficult to get them have a hang of it and get things right since the start.

Well, I see that I am responding to a very old thread but if it's still the case, I would recommend getting only the developers who have worked sufficiently well using Github. Indeed, as a member of an IT consulting company, I manage a team of devs that do it regularly and I understand the challenges developers face while starting to use Github, particularly because of enormous flexibility Github offers.

Comment: Hehe...yeah, this question is really old.  I have a lot more experience now and I think I know how to handle this situation.  However, I've changed jobs and don't have to deal with it anymore!